# Theming views that use node row style

Tags: views, 6, theming

I have a view that uses node rows. I looked at views-view-row-node.tpl.php and it only contains 4 lines. I tried to override the theme by using my node.tpl.php code in a new file but got this warning:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/public_html/sites/all/themes/templates/overrides/views-view-row-node--taxonomy-term-attachment.tpl.php on line 36.

How can I use a modified version of node.tpl.php to theme a certain display of my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably missunderstood the two different templates here

- The node template(node.tpl.php): This is for rendering a specific node
- views template This is for wrapping the node + comments

So all you have to do is to use the node.tpl.php to theme a single file.